# How to render specific component attribute according to route name

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

In Vue when I need to apply certain classes according to route I do `:class="$route.name == 'canceled' ? 'active' : ''"`.

How can I apply the same method in `v-btn` attribute itself and render `<v-btn outline>` or just `<v-btn>` according to route name.

Comment: By 'attribute' I mean adding ```outlined``` or removing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`outline` attribute value can be bound with `v-bind` directive or `:` colon shorthand. As [the documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes) explains, boolean value will result in adding or removing HTML attribute:

```
<v-btn :outline="$route.name == 'canceled'">
```